# Conditional EXEC dbo statement. Force error if exists, else succeed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to write a script that will exit as an error when there are currently SQL agent jobs running. I would also like it to succeed (exit 0) if there are no jobs running.

Something like below.

```
IF
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_help_job @execution_status=1
THEN
RAISE ERROR
ELSE
COMPILE SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will help you. You may need to change the code for your required action.
First, you need to create a Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE YourProc
    AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @ErrMsg NVARCHAR(MAX), @ErrSeverity INT
SET XACT_ABORT OFF
BEGIN TRY
    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view job  
        INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity activity 
            ON job.job_id = activity.job_id 
        WHERE activity.run_Requested_date IS NOT NULL  
          AND activity.stop_execution_date IS NULL) 
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @ErrMsg = 'There is a Job already running',
                @ErrSeverity = 1;
        RAISERROR (@ErrMsg, @ErrSeverity, 1);
    END
    ELSE
        PRINT 'No Jobs running'
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT  @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
            @ErrSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY();
    RAISERROR (@ErrMsg, @ErrSeverity, 1);
END CATCH
END
```

Then, you can call your procedure:

```
EXEC YourProc
```